# PHP session data lost in https

Tags: php, session, https

I recently updated my domain to https. But after that all pages that uses php $_SESSIONS stopped working as it should. $_SESSION simply empties when I reload a page even if all the pages have session_start() at the beggining.

In HTTP they work like a charm, in HTTPS they dont.

I even set a test page. Here is the code

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['test'])) {
    $_SESSION['test'] = $_GET['test'];
    echo '<script>window.location = \'session.php\'</script>';
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
    echo 'session empty!<br/>';
} else {

    echo $_SESSION['test'] . '<br/>';  
}

var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

when I test `session.php?test=hello` on http this is the result:

```
hello
array(2) { ["idprov"]=> string(1) "2" ["test"]=> string(5) "hello" }
```

when I test it in https I get the following error:

**session empty!**
**array(0) { }**

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to clear your cookies? The PHP-session_id is stored in a cookie and the cookie might be "locked" to http. This is just a guess =)

Comment: it didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

the problem was server implemenation and PHP Version. Change it, all was good.